# Implementation of conditional WGAN-GP in Keras

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am extending the WGAN-GP to be conditional from code base found here: 
https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/wgan_gp/wgan_gp.py

When I train the model, it doesn't seem to be conditioned on the labels. This is how I build my model.

```
    # The generator takes noise and the target label (states) as input
    # and generates the corresponding samples of that label
    noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_size, ), name="noise")
    label = Input(shape=(self.label_size, ), name="labels")
    real_samples = Input(shape=(self.input_size,), name="real")

    self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
    self.generator = self.build_generator([noise, label])

    # First we train the discriminator
    self.generator.trainable = False
    fake_samples = self.generator([noise, label])

    fake = self.discriminator([fake_samples, label])
    valid = self.discriminator([real_samples, label])

    interpolated = Lambda(self.random_weighted_average)([real_samples, fake_samples])
    valid_interp = self.discriminator([interpolated, label])

    self.d_model = Model([real_samples, noise, label],
                         [valid, fake, valid_interp],
                         name="discriminator")

    # Time to train the generator
    self.discriminator.trainable = False
    self.generator.trainable = True

    noise_gen = Input(shape=(self.latent_size,), name="noise_gen")

    fake_samples = self.generator([noise_gen, label])
    valid = self.discriminator([fake_samples, label])

    self.g_model = Model([noise_gen, label], valid, name="generator")
    self.g_model.compile(loss=self.wasserstein_loss, optimizer=optimizer)
```

Plotting the model results in:

[image: conditional WGAN-GP]

I don't know how to interpret the merged arrows on the right. The label should be concatenated IN the discriminator. I have a feeling this line messes something up:

```
    self.d_model = Model([real_samples, noise, label],
                         [valid, fake, valid_interp],
                         name="discriminator")
```

Since I'm just passing the label and I don't know how Keras routes that input to the other outputs..